# cannot save data to a json column in mysql with spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following JSON request:

```json
{ 
  "shortname":"test",
  "fullname":"Bogdan Onyshenko",
  "address":"Пр. Победы 72в",
  "telephone":"0669829242",
  "website":"http://193.70.37.242/index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap",
  "foundationyear":"2004",
  "sociallinks":[
    {
      "network":"facebook",
      "linkpage":"fb.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

My column is defined as follows:

```
@Column(name = "sociallinks")
@Convert(converter = StringMapConverter.class)
@ElementCollection
private  List<Map<String, String>> sociallinks;
```

The data that gets in my string converter class is follows:

```
{
  "network" : "facebook",
  "linkpage" : "fb.com"
}
```

And this is how controller method works:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Buildcompanies> createCompany(@RequestBody Buildcompanies company) {
        System.out.println("s links");
        System.out.println(company.getSociallinks());
      
        Buildcompanies _company = buildcompaniesRepository
            .save(new Buildcompanies(company.getFullname(), company.getShortname(), company.getAddress(), company.getTelephone(), company.getWebsite(), company.getSociallinks(), company.getFoundationyear()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(_company, HttpStatus.CREATED);


}
```

This is what println gives back in a controller method:

```
[{network=facebook, linkpage=fb.com}]
```

After I try to post data I get an error that column social networks doesn't have a default value. I wonder why and how to save it?

**stack trace**

```
2022-01-20 12:32:02.926 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : OPTIONS "/buildcompanies/add", parameters={}
2022-01-20 12:32:02.927 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.controller.BuildingcompaniesController#createCompany(Buildcompanies)
2022-01-20 12:32:02.928 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-01-20 12:32:02.931 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/buildcompanies/add", parameters={}
2022-01-20 12:32:02.931 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.controller.BuildingcompaniesController#createCompany(Buildcompanies)
2022-01-20 12:32:02.932 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.example.model.Buildcompanies@6108b3e8]
s links
[{network=facebook, linkpage=fb.com}]
2022-01-20 12:32:02.933 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2022-01-20 12:32:02.933 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
converter
{
  "network" : "facebook",
  "linkpage" : "fb.com"
}
2022-01-20 12:32:02.936 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into buildingcompanies (address, foundationyear, fullname, shortname, telephone, website, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-01-20 12:32:02.936  WARN 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2022-01-20 12:32:02.936 ERROR 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'sociallinks' doesn't have a default value
2022-01-20 12:32:02.936  INFO 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-01-20 12:32:02.937 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
2022-01-20 12:32:02.938 ERROR 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'sociallinks' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.controller.BuildingcompaniesController.createCompany(BuildingcompaniesController.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-01-20 12:32:02.939 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2022-01-20 12:32:02.940 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-01-20 12:32:02.940 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-01-20 12:32:02.941 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Thu Jan 20 12:32:02 EET 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/buildcompani (truncated)...]
2022-01-20 12:32:02.942 DEBUG 7188 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

**Entity**

```
package com.example.model;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.example.helpers.StringMapConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
@Entity
@Table(name = "buildingcompanies")

public class Buildcompanies {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "shortname")
    private String shortname;
    @Column(name = "fullname")
    private String fullname;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private String telephone;
    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;
    @Column(name = "sociallinks")
      @Convert(converter = StringMapConverter.class)
    @ElementCollection

    private  List<Map<String, String>> sociallinks;
    
    @Column(name = "foundationyear")
    private String foundationyear;
    private transient double rating;
    
    public Buildcompanies() {

    }

    public Buildcompanies(String shortname, String fullname, String address, String telephone, String website,
            List<Map<String, String>> sociallinks, String foundationyear) {
        this.shortname = shortname;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.address = address;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.website = website;
        this.sociallinks = sociallinks;
        this.foundationyear = foundationyear;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getShortname() {
        return shortname;
    }

    public void setShortname(String shortname) {
        this.shortname = shortname;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getSociallinks() {
        return sociallinks;
    }

    public void setSociallinks(List<Map<String, String>> sociallinks) {
        this.sociallinks = sociallinks;
    }

    public String getFoundationyear() {
        return foundationyear;
    }

    public void setFoundationyear(String foundationyear) {
        this.foundationyear = foundationyear;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

        
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: It would be good to post the stacktrace here

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Just posted it.

Comment: why in your save() method do you create a new instance of class Buildcompanies instead of just passing your company instance?

Comment: @MichaelGantman Simply because it worked on a previous tables without JSON columns

Comment: Plus if I remove the new class instance I get a following error he method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Buildcompanies,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String, List<Map<String,String>>, String)

Comment: I think I got the problem reason it is because of element colection anotation. It created a table buildcompany_sociallinks in db instead of saving the array to a JSON column.

Comment: Well. I would go with creation of an other table. Since data is stil present and shown. But now question is remaining. And It would sound like Does JPA support JSON column nativly? Because the reason for it in MySQL 5.7 sims to me useless. Only where it works properly is in PHP

Comment: Post full entity class. Maybe it's something wrong with your entity, especially `ID`. And what about @Transactional? Did you handle that?